# One slicer to filter multiple Excel tables (not pivot tables)

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

Is it possible to filter two ordinary Excel tables (**NOT** pivot tables) with one slicer? There is the same header name on both tables.

I can only think of two separate slicers and some VBA action based on events.